# Android. write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe) when use Process

Tags: android, file, epipe

Hello I tried to install app inside of my app via Process. For that function I created this method.

```
private void loadAndInstallApk(String string) {
    if(!isRooted()){
        return;
    }
    Uri uri = loadApk(string);
    if(uri == null){
        return;
    }
    Process p = null;
    DataOutputStream outs = null;
    try
    {

        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "system/bin/sh"});
        outs=new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());

        String cmd="pm install -r " + uri.getPath();
        Log.d(TAG, "DATA = cmd = " + cmd);
        outs.writeBytes(cmd + "\n");

        // Close the terminal
        outs.writeBytes("exit\n");
        outs.flush();
            p.waitFor();
            if (p.exitValue() != 255) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DATA succerss " + p.exitValue());
                // Sucess 
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "DATA Fail " + p.exitValue());
                // Fail
            }
        }
    catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("Error", e.toString(), e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.toString(), e);
    } finally {
        if(outs != null) {
            try {
                outs.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString(), e);
            }
        }
        try {
            File f = new File(uri.getPath());
            f.delete();
        }catch (NullPointerException e) {

            Log.e(TAG, "DATA = finally delete " + e.toString(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

But it fails when it calls

```
        outs.writeBytes(cmd + "\n");
```

Error message:

```
E/Error﹕ java.io.IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
java.io.IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:455)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:187)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeBytes(DataOutputStream.java:156)
...
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
        at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:202)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:197)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:450)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:187)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeBytes(DataOutputStream.java:156)
```

Instead of

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "system/bin/sh"});
```

I tried:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

It didn't help.

Also this code work for my root tablet but it doesn't work for my TV box.

I check device on root via methods:

```
private static boolean isRooted() {
    return findBinary("su");
}

public static boolean findBinary(String binaryName) {
    boolean found = false;
    if (!found) {
        String[] places = {"/sbin/", "/system/bin/", "/system/xbin/", "/data/local/xbin/",
                "/data/local/bin/", "/system/sd/xbin/", "/system/bin/failsafe/", "/data/local/"};
        for (String where : places) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DATA where = " + where);
            if ( new File( where + binaryName ).exists() ) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

It return true.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I found a solution. Problem was that my device has another command instead of "su" command

Comment: Really? That's your answer to your questions? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @user951793 Yes, it's try. I connected with manufacturer(as I made a app for exactly device, so I could get in touch with them) and as it turned out there was another command instead of "su"(sorry, I cannot write this command here, because I cannot divulgence of this data)